# Handling DB connections and Env config in DDD (clean/hexagonal) architecture

Tags: go, database-design, architecture, domain-driven-design

While I grasped the general idea, I'm having trouble seeing the best practice for managing config envs and managing the DB connection.

Meaning:

1. If I have the repository (for PostgreSQL for example), should I pass the NewRepository function the DB configuration? Will it not somehow adversely affect the architecture principles (maintenance, testability, etc.)?
2. How do we handle things like defer db.Close()?

   I mean, we'd obviously want it to defer in relation to the scope main function, so it's problematic to move that code into the Repository "class" (unless there's a way to do that with Context?)

   On the other hand, calling NewRepository in main scope but then having the db handle the connection outside of it feels kind of strange.

   Most of  the  examples I've found used the main function so it was easy. The question is how do you that correctly when employing the DDD (clean/hexagonal) architecture ? especially so that all the pieces would be "pluggable" without having to change the code "around it".

Here is an example I put together, is there a violation of some principles of the ddd pattern here? or is it actually how these things are done?

**1. Shouldn't I handle the defer db.Close() inside the repository itself? maybe with Context I can defer it in relation to the main function scope but inside the repository itself?**

**2. Should I really pass the config into the NewRepository ?**

**pkg/main.go :**

```
func main() {

    // get configuration stucts via .env file
    configuration, err := config.NewConfig()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    postgresRepo, err := postgres.NewRepository(configuration.Database)

    defer postgresRepo.DB.Close()


    myService := autocomplete.NewService(postgresRepo)

    handler := rest.NewHandler(myService)

    ...
    ...
    ...

}
```

**pkg/config/config.go:**

```
// Config is a struct that contains configuration variables
type Config struct {
    Environment string
    Port        string
    Database    *Database
}

// Database is a struct that contains DB's configuration variables
type Database struct {
    Host     string
    Port     string
    User     string
    DB       string
    Password string
}

// NewConfig creates a new Config struct
func NewConfig() (*Config, error) {
    env.CheckDotEnv()
    port := env.MustGet("PORT")
    // set default PORT if missing
    if port == "" {
        port = "3000"
    }
    return &Config{
        Environment: env.MustGet("ENV"),
        Port:        port,
        Database: &Database{
            Host:     env.MustGet("DATABASE_HOST"),
            Port:     env.MustGet("DATABASE_PORT"),
            User:     env.MustGet("DATABASE_USER"),
            DB:       env.MustGet("DATABASE_DB"),
            Password: env.MustGet("DATABASE_PASSWORD"),
        },
    }, nil
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing the database configuration into your repository, try passing the database connection. For example:

```golang
func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "...")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    repo := postgres.NewAutocompleteRepo(db)
    svc := autocomplete.NewService(repo)
    handler := autocomplete.NewHTTPHandler(svc)
}
```

This will leave the responsibility of connecting to the database outside of the repository and allow for easier testing.

Comment: thanks for the advice. Is having the `sql.Open(..)` (and similar lines for different DBs) outside the Repository classes really easier to test than having that logic inside the respository, and then accessing that DB in main scope to defer close it (like in my example in the post)?  it will allow to pass the repositories only the configuration which can be mocked quite easily. Am I missing something? thank you

Comment: also, just for general knowledge, can the context of Main be passed into different 'classes' and then using that Main Context to defer stuff?  Is that something that's possible or recommended in Go ?

Comment: @BVtp Unless you have the requirement of needing a different connection configuration per repository, I don't see why you would manage it there.

Comment: because then you would not need to expose the db reference to main function. For example, in your answer you have 5 lines of code pertaining the client for a specific db that some service needs. What if we add Redis now? and BoltDB? we would initialize the db client in main and then pass the clients to the repositories?  what if would move those first 5 lines of code into the repo code ?

Comment: @BVtp I don't see having one or more database connections in the main function as being a problem.

Yes, if you started using Redis, you would open the connection in the main function and pass it into the Redis repositories the same way my example does for Postgres.